# Question marks when I use rail package

Tags: packages, diagrams

I'm trying to compile syntax diagrams with the `rail` package, but all diagrams, no matter how large, come out like the following screenshot, a single rounded box with three question marks in it.

[image]

Sorry for my stupid question, but can anyone tell me the proper usage of this? I'm getting this when trying to compile the "Syntax Diagrams for LaTeX" document found here: http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/support/rail/rail.tex

```
The \Rail\ package allows you to include syntax diagrams (also known as
\emph{railroad diagrams}) in a \LaTeX\ document. Such a diagram looks
like this:
\label{example}
\begin{rail}

decl : 'def' identifier '=' ( expression + ';' )
     | 'type' identifier '=' type
     ;

\end{rail}
(If you like arrow-heads where the lines enter the boxes, a nice feature
contributed by J.~Olsson, see Section \ref{sec:options}.)
```

I just downloaded the rail package from ctan, unzipped it, moved `rail.sty` to `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/rail`, and upated my db with `texhash`. The rails package I downloaded came with a `.exe` file, but I don't see anything that I think will run on Ubuntu, which is what I'm using.

Comment: You have to run the `rail` program; the distribution provides an `exe` file (I guess for Windows) and C sources to be compiled. Running `make` on my machine raises errors and the program doesn't compile.

Comment: Gah! It raises errors and doesn't compile on mine as well: `/bin/sh: 1: flex: not found
make: *** [lex.c] Error 127`

Comment: And after instaling `flex`, running `make` raises a bunch of `undefined reference` errors. I guess this is a wash.

Comment: Seventeen years is a lot of time: the C file is dated 1998-09-30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the final output requires running the accompanying `rail` program; the distribution provides an executable for Windows and the C sources.

However, trying to `make` the program raises a lot of errors. Unless you are able to compile the program properly, I don't think you can use the package. Note that the banner in `rail.c` is defined by

```
static char SccsId[]="@(#)rail 26-Jul-1998";
```

and seventeen years is a lot of time for this kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

I took the time and fixed a bunch of issues. You can find the [fixed version of the rails package on Github](https://github.com/Holzhaus/latex-rail/releases/latest):

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/Holzhaus/latex-rail/archive/v1.2.1.tar.gz | tar xzvf -
$ cd latex-rail-1.2.1

$  gcc --version | head -n 1
gcc (GCC) 6.3.1 20170306

$ make
bison -y  -dv gram.y
gram.y: warning: 2 reduce/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-rr]
cmp -s gram.c y.tab.c || cp y.tab.c gram.c
cmp -s gram.h y.tab.h || cp y.tab.h gram.h
gcc -DYYDEBUG -O   -c -o rail.o rail.c
gcc -DYYDEBUG -O   -c -o gram.o gram.c
flex  -t lex.l > lex.c
gcc -DYYDEBUG -O   -c -o lex.o lex.c
gcc -DYYDEBUG -O rail.o gram.o lex.o -o rail

$ rail --help
This is Rail, Version 1.2 #1
usage: rail [-+acdit] [file]
```